# Using log4net for live log viewing - what is the best appender/method/viewer

Tags: c#, .net, view, log4net

I've recently discovered `log4net` which is a great asset for me.  I'm currently logging events to a txt file using the `RollingLogFileAppender`. This works great but I'd really like to be able to have a logging viewer that I can pull up live.

So I want a window that I keep up when my application is running and when new items are logged, they get displayed in the window.  I can handle how to parse and display the info, I just don't know how to get that info sent to me live using `log4net`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about an application running on your machine or network, you can continue to log to the text file and use [Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) or [Baretail Pro](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretailpro/index.php) to view the files. (Prices currently range from $0 to $US 35)